# Does GPIO27 need special handling when used as digital input?

Tags: gpio, pi-pico

I have three rotary encoders (with switch) connected to GPIOs (16,17,18), (19,20,21), (22,26,27). For quick testing of working I/O, I put all of them to input mode, with internal pull-up, and watch whether the signal is detected correctly:

```py
from machine import Pin
for i in [16,17,18,19,20,21,22,26,27]:
    p=Pin(i,Pin.IN,Pin.PULL_UP)
    p.irq(trigger=Pin.IRQ_FALLING|Pin.IRQ_RISING,handler=(lambda _p: print('pin ',_p)))
```

Everything works except of GPIO27 (switch of the 3rd rotary encoder), it seems to be ground-connected all the time (but sometimes not connected at all), regardless of pressing/depressing the button. I double-checked the wiring, soldering etc and everything looks okay. Is there something special about GPIO27 (e.g. does it need to be set as digital input in a special way, being an ADC by default? does it have internal pull-up at all?) or is it definitely a hw issue on my side?

Comment: just exchange the connections ... if behavior moves to another pin, then the switch is suspect

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of anything special about GPIO 27 compared to GPIO 26 and GPIO 28 which may also be connected to the internal ADC.